# input code needs a slight modification

Tags: excel, vba

With this code, specified cells are copied into a database worksheet and then clears the data form for the next entry.  How can I modify the code so that one (or perhaps more than one) cell is not cleared?

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

Dim historyWks As Worksheet
Dim inputWks As Worksheet

Dim nextRow As Long
Dim oCol As Long

Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCopy As String
Dim myCell As Range
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "sallygary"
'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
myCopy = "g12,g14,g18,g20,g22,g24,i16,i18,i20,i22,i24,k16,k18,k20,k22,k24,m16,m18,m20,m22,m24,o16,o18,o20,o22,o24,q16,q18,q20,q22,q24,s16,s18,s20,s22,s24,u16,u18,u20,u22,u24"

Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
Set historyWks = Worksheets("1_Data")

With historyWks
    nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End With

With inputWks
    Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)

    'If Application.CountA(myRng) <> myRng.Cells.Count Then
    '    MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
    '   Exit Sub
    'End If
End With

With historyWks
    With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
        .Value = "e4"
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" 'hh:mm:ss
    End With
    .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
    oCol = 3
    For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
        historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
        oCol = oCol + 1
    Next myCell
End With

'clear input cells that contain constants
With inputWks
  On Error Resume Next
     With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
          .ClearContents
          Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
     End With
  On Error GoTo 0
End With
ActiveSheet.Protect "sallygary"
Range("g12").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to loop through `myRng.Cells` as you did before.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This isn't my code. I want to add a cell to copy but not to clear. If I add it to the group, it will also clear that, of course. I wish that I was better at this.  On the line where the code readsvalue equals "eve for "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another string variable similar to the `myCopy` var.

```
dim myCopy as string, myClear as string
'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
myCopy = "g12,g14,g18,g20,g22,g24,i16,i18,i20,i22,i24,k16,k18,k20,k22,k24,m16,m18,m20,m22,m24,o16,o18,o20,o22,o24,q16,q18,q20,q22,q24,s16,s18,s20,s22,s24,u16,u18,u20,u22,u24"
'cells to CLEAR from Input sheet
myClear = "g12,g18,g22,i16,i20,i24,k18,k22,m16,m20,m24,o18,o22,q16,q20,q24,s18,s22,u16,u20,u24"
```

Now use that range definition to clear the cell contents.

```
 With .Range(myClear).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
      .ClearContents
      Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
 End With
```